# DirectShow ISampleGrabber which accepts VIDEOINFOHEADER2

Tags: windows, directshow

As stated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377544(VS.85).aspx, ISampleGrabber accepts only videos with VIDEOINFOHEADER structure, but not VIDEOINFOHEADER2. Is there any alternative to ISampleGrabber, or any example code for a filter that would do similar job? I have tried with IBasicVide, but it renders video on the screen which I would like to avoid. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your own filter for this goal.

There is already a sample in the SDK. See the [dump filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388553%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) sample.
If the renderer sample is too complex, use a transform filter and insert a NullRenderer behind this filter.